# Trouble adding to a existing JMS queue in a migration

Tags: java, spring-boot, queue, jms, activemq-classic

Currently I'm working on a migration and the existing project has feature to add data to a queue. It is currently been done as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="sendEmailEndpoint">
   <address uri="jms:/VirtualTopic.send.email?transport.jms.ConnectionFactory=myTopicConnectionFactory"/>
</endpoint>
```

My task is to remove this and do the same thing in without using these xml way.
I cannot change the destination. Currently I have develop a sample destination listener for the testing purpose which is listed below. As of now, I'm getting destination as `queue://VirtualTopic.send.email`.
Following is the my implementation to add to the queue

```
    private void sendToJms(String message) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Sending an email message.");
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("Virtual.send.email", message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("--------------- Exception ---------------" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Following is the listener that I created for testing purpose

```
@JmsListener(destination = "Virtual.send.email")
private void listener(String message, @Header(JmsHeaders.DESTINATION) String destination) {
   try {
       LOG.info("--------------------- message ----------------------- {}", message);
       LOG.info("--------------------- destination ----------------------- {}", destination);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       LOG.error("Error", e);

   }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
spring.activemq.username=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
spring.activemq.package.trust-all=true
```

Can anyone help me on this. Thank you

Comment: You didn't actually describe what the problem is. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I want to create the queue url as following format -> 
jms:/VirtualTopic.send.email?transport.jms.ConnectionFactory=myTopicConnectionFactory

Comment: In ActiveMQ the queue doesn't really have a URL. It just has a name. The only URL is for the connection factory and you're using `tcp://localhost:61616` for that.

Comment: can you guild me how to add to the destination queue in "jms:/VirtualTopic.send.email?transport.jms.ConnectionFactory=myTopicConnectionFactory" format. I'm little bit new to this area.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. I don't recognize that "format" for a queue, and I don't know where or why you're trying to use it.

Comment: I may be asking the question in wrong way since I'm not much familiar much to the context I'm really sorry about that. I have updated the question. Hope now it is clear

Answer (score 0):

The reference to "myTopicConnectionFactory" is telling the framework to point to another definition. That looks to be defining a javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory -- which only supports topics.

Either:

1. Add a new definition for a QueueConnectionFactory

or

2. Update the defintion to be a javax.jms.ConnectionFactory that supports both topics and queues

Note: Is this a framework? If so, which one? Spring Integration, Apache Camel or Mule?

Comment: Queue destination is in Elastic Path. Currently adding to the queue done from ESB(xml) which I'm trying to replace with java in a Spring Boot application